# Need Help for connecting MSSQL SERVER From Linux(ubuntu)

Tags: linux, perl, unixodbc

I just installed the ODBC driver in the Ubuntu, but still I am facing issues while connecting the database from Perl. Here is the description on what I have done in my machine.

I installed the MSSQL Driver and Unix ODBC from easysoft website. The path details in my machine follows:

ODBC Installed Path:- `user/local/easysoft/unixodbc`

Data Source and Driver path: `user/local/etc` Sample Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict;  
use DBI;   
my $dsn="DBI:ODBC:DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1433;database=DB_name";  
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, "username", "password" ,{AutoCommit => 1} )
            or die DBI::errstr;
```

Error:

```
DBI connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1433;database=DB_name','username',...) failed: unixODBCDriver Manager Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (SQL-01000) at sample.pl line 5 
unixODBCDriver ManagerCan't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (SQL-01000) at sample.pl line 5.
```

Comment: What are the contents of you /etc/odbcinst.ini file?

Answer (score 2):

```
DRIVER={SQL Server}
```

You code is attepmting to connect to a [SQL Server] driver in your odbcinst.ini file. However if you are using the [Easysoft ODBC-SQL Server Driver](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-sql-server-driver/index.html) you will need to use :-

```
Driver={Easysoft ODBC-SQL Server}
```